# Horizontal Accordion Toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just started learning jQuery and am trying to create a section on my personal site that has a list of images in a row, when someone clicks on the image a paragraph shows up.

**Code** - https://jsfiddle.net/ceo123/my4Lhkkv/3/

```
<section>
  <img class="expand-one" src="" alt="Number 1" />
  <p class="content-one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

  <img class="expand-two" src="" alt="Number 2" />
  <p class="content-two">This is the second paragraph.</p>

  <img class="expand-three" src="" alt="Number 3" />
  <p class="content-three">This rocks! Let's work on some more stuff.</p>
</section>
```

The paragraph should -

- Appear below the img and left align to the section
- When another img is selected, the p changes to the appropriate selection
- The text in the p show take up the width of the section
- If the screen width is reduced and the imgs stack, the p should still expand under its img row and the next one

**My question** - How can I get the direction of the toggle to slide down and then for the p text to be left aligned in the section each time? Thanks!

Edit #1: I updated my code. Reached far, but can't center the expanding section.

Edit #2: Solution - https://jsfiddle.net/92uhs075/2/
Worked on it and solved the problem without jQuery, using only html and css.

Answer (score 0):

I might be off.  Was this what you were looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/my4Lhkkv/4/

```
<section>
<div class="images">
  <img class="expand-one" src="" alt="Number 1" />
  <img class="expand-two" src="" alt="Number 2" />
  <img class="expand-three" src="" alt="Number 3" />
</div>

<div class="text">
  <p class="content-two">This is the second paragraph.</p>
  <p class="content-one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <p class="content-three">This rocks! Let's work on some more stuff.</p>
</div>
</section>

img {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  display: none;
}

.text {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I was looking when someone clicks on the img the corresponding p text appears on the bottom. So if img - number 1 is clicked, then the p - "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit" shows up